# Inner join query for my Android application

Tags: java, android, sql, inner-join

I'm making this Android application. A page on the application has to display data from 2 different columns in my database it has to collect the data from the workshops table, and the schedules table where the workshopid is equal. I know I have to use an innerjoin on the workshopid, but this doesnt seem to work for me.

This is my code right now:

```
 private void GetInfo(String eventName, String workshopName) {
    String GetInfo = null;
    String dbResult = "empty";
    dbConnect database = new dbConnect(this);

    try{
        String query = "SELECT workshopid, scedules.workshopid, scedules.starttime, scedules.endtime, workshopname, workshopdesc FROM workshops INNER JOIN scedules ON workshops.workshopid = scedules.workshopid WHERE workshopname = '" + workshopName + "';";
        GetInfo = "?query=" + URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
        String link = "https://jackstest.000webhostapp.com/androiddbconnect.php" + GetInfo;
        dbResult = database.execute(link).get();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Header.setText("Workshop");
    }

    try{
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(dbResult);
        JSONObject jo = null;
        data = new String[ja.length()];
        data2 = new String[ja.length()];

        for (int i = 0;i < 1 ; i++){
            jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            data[i] = jo.getString("workshopname");
            data2[i] = jo.getString("workshopdesc");
        }

        Header.setText(data[0]);
        Content.setText(data2[0]);
        Location.setText("Locatie : " + eventName);

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Content of the workshops table :

`workshopid: "1",
workshopname: "Workshop1",
imagelink: "",
workshopdesc: " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"`

Content of the schedules table :

```
eventid: "1",
workshopid: "1",
starttime: "13:23:00",
endtime: "13:25:00",
date: "2018-04-03"
```

Out of these 2 tables, from the workshops i need workshopname, workshopdesc, imagelink. And from the schedules table i need the starttime, endtime and date.

Comment: Please edit your question to remove all the unnecessary spaces in order to make it readable. Also, perhaps any unnecessary code too (see [mcve]).

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work for me" is a bit vague. What happens? An Error message? Wrong result? Computer catches fire?

Comment: `doesn't seem to work for me` is possibly the worst problem statement you can make on a forum.  What ***exactly*** is the issue?  Does it error, if so what are the error messages?  Does it given "incorrect" results?  If so, what are those results, what should the results be, and what are the contents of the tables *(the inputs)*?  Do other simpler queries work in the structure you've written?  Etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Post the result of running the queries: `select * from workshops` and `select * from schedules`

Comment: You need to give an example of what you are getting and what you are expecting. Keep the example as brief as possible

Comment: it is not throwing any errors, its also not giving me any data. I edited my post so that you guys can see the contents of the tables.

Comment: Does your query run in SSMS and return rows? Is your table actually called `scedules` and not `schedules`? Is the value of `workshopName` = `'Workshop1'` exactly?

Comment: Does your java work when trying a simpler query *(with no joins)*?  That test will help isolate if you have a Java problem or a SQL problem...

Comment: @JacobH they only thing that is available for me is the PHP file that the data is in so i cant test it in SSMS. And yes it is called scedules, and yes it is called Workshop1 exactly.

Comment: @MatBailie It is a SQL problem since it is giving the data back if i use a simpeler query.

Comment: Then the contents of the table isn't what you think.  Either the columns you're joining on don't quite match *(white space, strange unicode characters, etc)* or the column in your where clause doesn't match your `workshopName` parameter.  Can you echo out the value of `query` after you've built it but before you're executed it?  Can you show the results of executing `"SELECT * FROM workshops WHERE  workshopname = '" + workshopName + "';"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL statement and see if it gives the result you expect:

```
String query = "SELECT w.workshopid, s.starttime, s.endtime, w.workshopname, w.workshopdesc 
FROM workshops AS w
INNER JOIN scedules AS s ON 
w.workshopid = s.workshopid 
WHERE w.workshopname = '" + workshopName + "';";
```

If this doesn't work I will need to know what type of database you are accessing (MySQL, MS SQL, ...).

Also: I noticed this line of code:

```
database.execute(link).get();
```

Is `database` an `AsyncTask` ? If so then using the method `get()` will block you thread until the response is back--effectively making an `AsyncTask` useless.